# Отрисовка нового окна в qml

Tags: c++, gui, qml, дизайн

Подскажите как открыть новое окно поверх основного ? 
Есть следующий код написанный на `C`:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
qmlRegisterType<BackEnd>("io.backend", 1, 0, "BackEnd");
BackEnd backEnd;
QQmlContext* cntx = engine.rootContext();
cntx->setContextProperty("backEnd", &backEnd);
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
return app.exec();
}
```

Тут отрисовываю первое окно и с ним все в порядке, по нажатию на кнопку хочу открыть новое окно поверх старого.
Вот код нового окна:

```
ApplicationWindow {
id: myItem
signal message(string msg)
width: 600; height: 400
GridLayout {
   id: gridLayout
   columns: 4
   width: parent.width
   height: parent.height / 3
   anchors.margins: 160
   anchors.bottomMargin: 50
   rowSpacing: 50
   columnSpacing: 200
   anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right; bottom: parent.bottom }

   CustomButton {
       id: start
       text: "qwert"
       Layout.columnSpan: 2
       Layout.fillHeight: true
       Layout.fillWidth: true
       onClicked: startMotor()
   }

   CustomButton {
       id: stop
       Layout.columnSpan: 2
       Layout.fillHeight: true
       Layout.fillWidth: true
       text:"12345"
       onClicked: stopMotor()
   }

   CustomButton {
       id: leftSector
       Layout.fillHeight: true
       Layout.fillWidth: true
       text: "fghjk"
       onClicked: changeColorLeftMode()

   }

}
}
```

Как вызвать его открытие по нажатию на кнопку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был найдет, но все же может быть кому то понадобиться по этому отвечу на него сам.
В мейн файле qml необходимо привязать по нажатию кнопки следующее.

```
onClicked: {
           var component = Qt.createComponent("exitWindow.qml")
           var window = component.createObject("root")
           window.show()
           mouse.accepted = false
        }
```